# Free web application (or framework) to manage sport group events

Tags: webapp-rec, open-source

I am looking for a free web application to manage the sport outings of my caving association.
I would like :

- a way for the members of my association to login (the other should not be able to see the events)
- a way for the members to create a new outing
- a way for the members to RSVP to an outing
- a calendar view of the next outings
- an email alert for all the new created outing

Something a little bit like http://www.meetup.com/ but for associations.

If there is no free web application available on internet, I am ready to create my own application (I am a developer). However I would like to start with a framework/CMS which could easily meet my needs.

Comment: I´ve just developed a facebook webapp that uses facebook platform to manage groups and events. It´s created to focus on sport groups. I guess it has features that can attend all of your requirements. Please, visit http[http://apps.facebook.com/sportgroup](http://apps.facebook.com/sportgroup) and check if the features can be used to your necessities.
Please, return a feedback for me, if you can.
Hope you enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of PHP User Groups are hosted on Meetup. I guess it's going to work for your association as well.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps for Business;

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html

Specifically the calendar features, could do all this for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

www.groops.de has, what you want.

Also closed groups, so other people on the platform have no insight into your group.

Just switch to English on the top-right.